# Is there any way to add value of two <h> tags using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `<h4>` tags, one which contain price, and another contains percentage value. I need to find the percentage and set into new `<h4>` tag.
I tried to calculate but which return `NaN` instead. I tried `alert(parseFloat(price)+parseFloat(percent))` which return concatenated result, not the sum(for just testing).

I tried following, value is assigned based on checkbox click.

```
$("#checkbox1").click(function () {
     if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
         var price = $("#tex2").text();
         var percent = $("#percent").text();
         price = parseFloat(price);
         percent= parseFloat(percent);
         var dis_price; 
         dis_price = parseFloat(dis_price); 
         dis_price = price-(percent/100)*price;
         $('#tex1').text(dis_price);

  }
  else {
      $("#tex1").text("test");
  }
});
```

I want to get calculated value instead of `NaN`. Please find me way to solve this problem.

Comment: add your HTML code, for analysing

Comment: Can you please include the relevant `HTML`  Also using `parseInt()` might be of some help.

Comment: could you show us what strings are in #tex2 and #percent ? maybe typo in #tex2 (#text2) ?

Comment: thank you guys for your replies. I got it. I added INR along with the price that what it shows Nan. I removed it hence its working.

Comment: @SaranPrasad Don't write your answer as comment, create an answer for it and accept. Answering your own question is perfectly fine if no one else give a valid answer,  if you think that your answer is better, or also worth mentioning.

Comment: @SaranPrasad  why do you accept the answer with `+tex2.innerText;` if you problem was the `INR` that was added along with the price? Because using `+` would also result in `NaN`, and would as of that not solve you original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without jquery it will be simpler (the `+` make implicit cast string to number)

```
var price = +tex2.innerText;
var per = +percent.innerText;
tex1.innerText = price-(per/100)*price;
```

```js
function make(check) {
  if(check.checked) {
    var price = +tex2.innerText;
    var per = +percent.innerText;
    tex1.innerText = price-(per/100)*price;
  } else {
    tex1.innerText = 'test';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="make(this)">Click</button>
<div>
  <h id="tex2">10</h>
  <h id="percent">20</h>

  <h id="tex1"></h>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A math operation on an `undefined` value will return `NaN`. Make sure your referenced values are not `undefined`.